# Why is DataSet.WriteXml occasionally writing NUL bytes to file? Can it be prevented?

Tags: .net, windows, dataset, storage, corruption

Our application has some XML setting files, the schema is in a DataSet, and the files are written with [DataSet.WriteXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.writexml?view=netframework-3.5).  Sometimes - though it is uncommon - the .xml files are filled with NUL (\0) bytes instead of the data and settings that are expected.  Why is this happening?  Is there any way to prevent the file from being filled with NUL bytes?

Comment: I might have recently been [wondering the same thing](https://superuser.com/questions/1500393/what-does-a-file-damaged-by-loss-of-write-behind-caching-look-like) ?

Comment: Yes!  That is exactly what is happening!  Sometimes the whole file is \0 NUL bytes, and occasionally it is just the trailing part.  I will be watching your question too, thanks

Comment: Looks like there might be something awry with the XML serializer then; interesting to  know it's not just me it's happening to

Comment: Are you using streams-oriented methods or filepath-oriented methods? If you're using streams, are you sure Dispose is called?

Comment: Just calling `public void WriteXml (string fileName)` on an instance of `DataSet` where `fileName` is he file name (including the path) to which to write.  Dispose is not being explicitly called (I'll double-check though).  It happens maybe 1 in a 1000 or even 1 in 10000 runs of the application.  Could be a power failure, or maybe a bug somewhere either in our code, .NET, drivers, who knows.  Very hard to reproduce.

Comment: Could you please share your code? Also event log data will be helpful

Comment: Pavel -- the event log data is a good idea.  I suspect this happens after a power failure (perhaps the user just held the power button until the PC shut off).  Unfortunately, it happened on customer machines not ours, and I didn't export the event logs.  Thank you for the suggestion though, if there was a system-wide failure that event logs could be very informative.  I'll update the question later with code, and notes about how it's disposed, confirm there is only a single thread involved, etc.

Comment: In the meantime, we have resorted to the application renaming the original settings file to xxxx.xml.backup before writing out an updated version.  Then, when it reads the file in, if there is an `XmlException`, we now attempt to load the backup file instead.